# nuber value is not allowed in uri segment 2, codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing, codeigniter-3

I have configures .htaccess as

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|uploads|assets|img|uploaded|admin|source|images|googlexxxxxxxx\.html|mobile.html)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and my routing is :

```
    $route['career/(:any)'] = 'career/index/$1';
```

and my url is :

```
    http://local.berger.com/career/4
```

But is says Page not found.
But if I just keep the url http://local.berger.com/career/ then its okay. Can't we put number in uri segment 2, or is there some problem with .htaccess ? Any kinds of suggestion are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use normal .htaccess
Here you can get that.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

After that your config file

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Replace with

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Your route is ok

```
$route['career/(:any)'] = 'career/index/$1';
```

Now your controller

```
public function index($variable){
    //code goes here
}
```

Now you are good to go.
Hope it works for you.